# How do I create a github release on every commit?

Tags: java, git, maven, github, travis-ci

I'm creating a github hobby project.  This app is meant for a non-technical person and I have a very fast feedback cycle.  The majority of the time when I make a commit, I want this person to download the latest change and try it out.  They don't know how to code so they'll need to download the artifact of the project.  I'm not sure how to make this new binary available on every commit.  Here's what I've got:

I configured travis-ci to create a release on every tag.  From what I've read, I can't have it do this on every commit.  But this will create a release if I do it on every push:

`` git tag release-`date +%s` -f && git push --tags -f && git push ``

This seems pretty complicated and indirect.  Is there an easier way to do this?

Here's my travis config:

```
language: java
jdk:
- oraclejdk8
script: mvn clean verify
deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key:
    secure: <redacted>
  file: /home/travis/build/my-name/my-project/target/my-project.jar
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    repo: my-project
    tags: true
```

Comment: Actually, looks straight-forward enough to me. But since this is a Maven project, don't you want to use the Release plugin and change its version on each release?

Comment: @Tunaki there's a lot of boilerplate to push to the public repo.  I don't think I plan to do that for this app.

Comment: Update: Although this releases every commit, it seems to release the same old file each time.  Not sure why.

Comment: It said it's not going to release the jar because it already exists.  I worked around this by changing my command above to this: ```git tag release-`date +%s` -f && git push --tags -f && git push```